# Jenkins JMeter Perfomance Plugin Error : Exception while determining absolute error/unstable threshold evaluation

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I am facing following error when running Performance Plugin on Jenkins for JMeter tests (I have source file setting on Performance Plugin set to `**/*.jtl`).

> Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 1% sets the build as unstable
>   Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 1% sets the build as failure
>   ERROR: Exception while determining absolute error/unstable threshold evaluation
>   java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
>       at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>       at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
>       at hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.perform(PerformancePublisher.java:581)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:401)

I was wondering if anybody has encountered this issue or better resolved it.

Comment: Run procmon with a filter on errors and see at which file this fails

Comment: @Marged - thanks a lot looking at my issue. I have my JENKINS_HOME set to C:\Jenkins. Had a look at the console logs again and saw that it is looking for the jtl at : Performance: Parsing JMeter report file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PERF - JOB\builds\37\performance-reports\JMeter\1808-1031-MYPERFORMANCEBenchmark.jtl'. How can I make him look at the workspace for the required file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was facing was related to running JMeter build job on Jenkins Node instead of Jenkins Master. I resolved the issue after upgrading to Performance Plugin version 3.3 (which had Pull request #97 merged). Thanks all for responding to my question and especially @UBIK LOAD PACK for pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of plugin you are using  but you may be facing this issue:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-43503

Comment: thanks for responding to my question. I checked the plugin version and it's 3.0 so think that should be fine. Any other pointers?

Comment: Thanks @UBIK LOAD PACK. Jenkins Home (Node) : C:\Jenkins || Directory structure within workspace : project-ui-tests/perf/target/jmeter/results/DDMM-HHMM-Perfor‌​manceTest.jtl || Publish Performance test result report configuration Source data files : project-ui-tests/perf/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl || Performance Plugin is looking for jtl at following location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PERF-JOB\builds\43\performance-reports\JM‌​eter\DDMM-HHMM-Perfo‌​rmanceTest.jtl